# Generate series from long-format data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df
      date      fruit    type   count   mean      comment
0   2010-01-05   apple   fruit    3    0.280949   apple is best
1   2010-01-05   banana  yellow   3    0.480949   banana not in stock
2   2010-01-05   apple    green   3    0.587949   apple is best
3   2010-01-05   bana     fruit   4    0.80949    banana not in stock
...
```

Is there a way to get a time series  series (x = year, y = mean) for each fruit and type combination. (I then can calculate the rolling mean; need generalisable code since there are many types).  For example for apple, I need two generate time series: apple_fruit and apple_green :

```
date         mean
2010-01-05   0.280949
...
```

```
date         mean
2010-01-05   0.587949   
...
```

Comment: why are your dates all the same?

Comment: I just added a comment variable for context.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to generate a time series, if your dates are all the same...

Comment: There are dates for every day for a few years. I just provided a snapshot for a sample of one day's worth.

Comment: so if you get several different dates for each fruit/type combination, which date would you want to keep?

Comment: The data is unique by fruit-type-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split the dataframe based on `fruit` and `type` columns using

```
l = list(df.groupby(['fruit', 'type']))
```

where `l[i][0]` will be the `fruit`, `type` combination and `l[i][1]` will the subset of the dataframe which matches the combination

#### Sample

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'date': pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01 09:30:00', periods=40, freq='d'),
                   'fruit': ['apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana']*10,
                   'type' : ['fruit', 'yellow', 'green', 'fruit']*10,
                   'count' : [3]*40,
                   'mean'  : np.random.randn(40),
})

for g in  list(df.groupby(['fruit', 'type'])):
    print ("{0} {1}".format(*g[0]))
    print (g[1][['date', 'mean']])
```

If your intention is to take rolling mean based on the `fruit`, `type` combination you can rather use

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby(['fruit', 'type'])['mean'].rolling(1).mean()
```

which does not need explicit splitting.

You can also do the same using

```
for g in list(df.sort_values('date').groupby(['fruit', 'type'])):
  print ("{0} {1}".format(*g[0]))
  print (g[1]['mean'].rolling(1).mean())
```

Comment: Does it generate the series since the end lines are print statements?